# IIS setting SSL to Require and Accept problem

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, ssl-certificate

I have a problem with a webApi application. This application should get a client certificate from the request and verify if the certificate is in Trusted Root CA of the local computer.
The problem is that if I set the SSL Settings from IIS on 'Require' 'Accept', I can't access the webApi anymore.
The error (from Mozilla) is: 
`"An error occurred during a connection to localhost. SSL received an unexpected Hello Request handshake message. Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_UNEXPECTED_HELLO_REQUEST "`

What I tried already:

- Setting the SSL Setting to "Require" "Ignore". The webApi will not see the certificate in the request.
- Tried to access the webApi by the issuer URI from the certificate.
  Here is the same problem
- Tried with SoapUi with the certificate attached gives me Socket Timeout
- Made a simple console application that makes a request to the webApi gives me `Could not establish trust relationship for SSL/TLS secure channel`

The certificate from the server is self-signed made in IIS and placed    in Trusted Root CA. I tried also other certificates but the problem    remains the same.

Do you have any ideas about this problem?

Comment: Try another browser first (ideally IE or Edge from Microsoft).

Answer (score 0):

The only solution i found was to change the OS on the server from Windows Server 2007 to Windows Server 2010 witch have the IIS version 10. I really could not find a solution for Windows 7.